# Double click on label not detected

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium with smart client,
 where i have ordinary HTML5 label defined with double click.

Some how Selenium does not trace double click event and fail my test.

I have check source of the page and I found label like this.

```
<label ondblclick="AddtoGrid($(this))">variable_counter</label>
```

Comment: Could you post your selenium code for double click?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Selenium, and, I use Selenium Browser automation framework. So I don't have any code but auto detected. It would be great if you can guide me how to write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire doubleclick event manually on Xpath.

Command   : FireEvent

Target    : xpath of a html control

Value     : dblclick (Note doubleClick does not work.)